# Top bar privileges link?

Tags: feature-request, privileges, top-bar, help

I think that a link for privileges should be put into the new top bar. It's really useful for new people. Maybe under 'help' would be a good place for it.

Comment: But if you click 'help' you can reach privileges from there..

Comment: TBH, the help center seems really cluttered, and it scares away new users.

Comment: @DantheMan So you should understand the motivation for avoiding cluttering the top bar with lots of links that would scare away new users.